# Upgrade subversion to 1.7 on opensuse other than build source code

Tags: linux, opensuse, yast

I'm using openSUSE Linux 11.4, it has Subversion 1.6.15 bundled. However, I'd like to upgrade to Subversion 1.7 today. However, the auto software update feature in YaST seems to only allow me to upgrade to 1.6.17.

Can YaST help me upgrade to SVN 1.7.x ? I know I can do it by building 1.7.x from source, but can YaST update it for me?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Add next software repositories and then try to upgrade subversion:
http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/tools:/scm:/svn/openSUSE_11.4/
http://download.opensuse.org/update/11.4/

There is also one-click install available on http://software.opensuse.org/

Comment: Thank you. Your hint works and now I have svn 1.7.4 with your URL. But could you tell me the difference between your URL and URLs listed at http://en.opensuse.org/Package_repositories#Oss ? BTW: I got to know the latter after I read your answer.

Comment: I suppose this was working back in 2012, but the link does not work any more.